# AWS Elasticsearch - how to see cluster resizing history in Cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, logging, amazon-cloudwatch

We have multiple `Elasticsearch` clusters on several `AWS` accounts. Some of them were resized up and down while we were testing the environments. Now we forgot which one we were experimenting with and we want to see the resizing history. Is there a way to retrieve it from `Cloudwatch` or any other logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't an easy way to exact events specific to resizing, but we can pull events from cloudtrail with EventName as UpdateElasticsearchDomainConfig.

```
aws cloudtrail lookup-events --lookup-attributes AttributeKey=EventName,AttributeValue=UpdateElasticsearchDomainConfig
```

or from console

[image]